# I need to avoid value less than ZERO, what should I have to make change in the query to get null if value of output is less than Zero

Tags: sql

This is SQL query for the data, I need to avoid value less than ZERO, what should I have to make change in the query to get null if value of output is less than Zero

```
SELECT 
    deviceID,
    SUBSTRING(data, 1,2) AS Device,
    SUBSTRING(data, 3,2) AS Device_Status,
    udf.test1(data) as Energy_TOT,
    udf.test2(data) as PWR,
    DATEADD(hour,4,EventEnqueuedUtcTime) AS ts
INTO [IOThuboutput]
FROM [IOThubinput]
```

Comment: Which value are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which value you are talking about.  However, you can use a `case` expression:

```
(case when val >= 0 then val end) as val
```

Many databases support the `greatest()` function as well.  So, if `val` is never `null`:

```
greatest(val, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this (udf.test1(data) as Energy_TOT) this output

Comment: @gagan . . . Parentheses can go around an expression, but not around the column alias definition.

Comment: if I want to run query only in the limited time eg. morning 9AM to evening 7PM how can I run it , same query

Comment: @Gagan . . . This answers your question about `NULL` values.  If you have another question about filtering for time -- and the documentation on date/time functions does not help -- then ask a new question, with sample data, desired results, and appropriate explanation and database tag.